# Orthogonality of the Gegenbauer Polynomials

Tags: calculus, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

Typically the orthogonality relation for the Gegenbauer polynomials is given as:

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}C_{n}^{\alpha}(x)C_{m}^{\alpha}(x)\cdot(1-x^2)^{\alpha-1/2}dx=\frac{\pi2^{1-2\alpha}\Gamma(2\alpha+n)}{n!(n+\alpha)(\Gamma(\alpha))^2}\delta_{mn}
$$

The Rodrigues formula for $C_{n}^{\alpha}(x)$ is given by:

$$
C_{n}^{\alpha}(x)=constant\cdot(1-x^2)^{-\alpha+1/2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left[(1-x^2)^{n+\alpha-1/2}\right]
$$

My question is the following:
How do I derive/proove the orthogonality relation?

In George Andrews' "Special Functions" Ch. 6, he proves the orthogonality relation for the Hermite and Laguerre polynomials by substituting the Rodrigues form of the polynomial in for one of the polynomials and then using integration by parts $n$ times.  However when I try that I get something like:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{m}(-1)^{k+1}C_{n-(k-1)}^{\alpha+(k-1)}(x)\frac{d^{m-k}}{dx^{m-k}}\left[(1-x^2)^{m+\alpha-1/2}\right]\bigg|_{-1}^{1}+\int_{-1}^{1}C_{n-m}^{\alpha+m}(x)\cdot(1-x^2)^{m+\alpha-1/2}dx
$$

I don't immediately see why all the terms in the summation go to zero, nor how to evaluate the integral directly.  Any ideas?

Comment: I noticed that if you substitute the Rodrigues formula in for $C_{n-m}^{\alpha+m}(x)$ in the integral of my result (equation 3) it evaluates to $constant\cdot\frac{d^{(n-m-1)}}{dx^{9n-m-1)}}\left[(1-x^2)^{n+\alpha-1/2}\right]\bigg|_{-1}^{1}$, but I still don't know how to evaluate this though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  You first expand $(1-x^2)^{m+\alpha-1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k{m+\alpha-1/2\choose k}x^{2k}$, using the binomial theorem.  You can then take the $(m-k)$-th derivative explicitly, which is $x^{-(m-k)}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k{n+l-1/2 \choose k}(2k)_{m-k}x^{2k}$, at $x=\pm1$ this summation converges to zero unless $k=m$, so only the last term in the sum is left and it also goes to zero since both $(1-1^2)^{m+\alpha-1/2}$ and $(1-(-1)^2)^{m+\alpha-1/2}$.  The integral can then be evaluated by invoking Rodrigues' formula again.

Comment: Could you explain why the summation converges to zero? You cannot use $k$ as the dummyindex in the second summation.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still interested in a different approach (I know, it has been over 10 years): The terms inside the sum all go to $0$, since the $m$-th derivative of $(1-z^2)^{m+\alpha-1/2}$ is gonna be the same parity as $m$, just like the $m$-th Gegenbauer polynomials, so you will always have an even function, which you evaluate at $1$ and $-1$ and then subtract from one another. That's always $0$. The integral will go to $0$ since you can just apply partial integration often enough for the Gegenbauer polynomial to vanish, while the weight function won't vanish. Didn't quite feel like going into much more detail since the question is so old already, but if you want, I can.

Answer (score 0):

**About the orthogonal**
We can start with the Jacobi ODE of second order reads

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[ \left( 1-x \right) ^{\alpha +1}\left( 1+x \right) ^{\beta +1}y' \right] +n\left( n+\alpha +\beta +1 \right) \left( 1-x \right) ^{\alpha}\left( 1+x \right) ^{\beta}y=0,
$$

and when $\alpha = \beta = \lambda - \frac{1}{2}$, the last eqn. reduced to gegenbauer ODE of 2-order:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[ \left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda +1/2}y' \right] +n\left( n+2\lambda \right) \left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda -1/2}y=0.
$$

We introduce some notations for convenient:

$$
C_{n}^{\lambda}\equiv C_{n\lambda}
$$

and we can write these ODEs

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[ \left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda +1/2}C_{n\lambda}' \right] +n\left( n+2\lambda \right) \left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda -1/2}C_{n\lambda}=0,
$$

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[ \left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda +1/2}C_{m\lambda}' \right] +m\left( m+2\lambda \right) \left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda -1/2}C_{m\lambda}=0,
$$

then use $
C_{m\lambda}
$ times the first eqn., $
C_{n\lambda}
$ times the second one, and subtract two results, we have:

$$
\left\{ C_{m\lambda}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[ \left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda +1/2}C_{n\lambda}' \right] -C_{n\lambda}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[ \left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda +1/2}C_{m\lambda}' \right] \right\} +\left[ n\left( n+2\lambda \right) -m\left( m+2\lambda \right) \right] \left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda -1/2}C_{n\lambda}C_{m\lambda}=0.
$$

Then integral the last eqn. in $\left[-1,1\right]$, the first term gives

$$
\int_{-1}^1{\left\{ C_{m\lambda}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[ \left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda +1/2}C_{n\lambda}' \right] -C_{n\lambda}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[ \left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda +1/2}C_{m\lambda}' \right] \right\} \mathrm{d}x}=\int_{-1}^1{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[ \left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda +1/2}\left( C_{m\lambda}C_{n\lambda}'-C_{n\lambda}C_{m\lambda}' \right) \right] \mathrm{d}x}=\left[ \left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda +1/2}\left( C_{m\lambda}C_{n\lambda}'-C_{n\lambda}C_{m\lambda}' \right) \right] _{-1}^{1}=0,
$$

so the second term must be $0$, i.e.

$$
\left[ n\left( n+2\lambda \right) -m\left( m+2\lambda \right) \right] \int_{-1}^1{\left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda -1/2}C_{n\lambda}C_{m\lambda}\mathrm{d}x}=0.
$$

for $m \ne n$. This identity is equivalent to the orthogonal relation

$$
\int_{-1}^1{\left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda -1/2}C_{n\lambda}C_{m\lambda}\mathrm{d}x}=0.\quad \left( m\ne n \right) 
$$

---

**About the coefficient**
As the Gegenbauer polynolmials is a special condition of the Jacobi one, we start calculate it with the orthogonal coefficient of Jacobi polynomials.The definition of Jacobi polynomials reads

$$
w_n:=_2F_1\left( -n,p+n,\gamma ,z \right) =\sum_{k=0}^n{\left( -1 \right) ^k\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n\\
 k\\
\end{array} \right) \frac{\left( p+n \right) _k}{\left( \gamma \right) _k}z^k}.
$$

Denoted the coefficient as $N_n$, the integral

$$
N_n=\int_0^1{w_{n}^{2}z^{\gamma -1}\left( 1-z \right) ^{p-\gamma}\mathrm{d}z}=\frac{\Gamma \left( \gamma \right)}{\Gamma \left( \gamma +n \right)}\int_0^1{w_n\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}z^n}\left[ z^{\gamma +n-1}\left( 1-z \right) ^{p+n-\gamma} \right] \mathrm{d}z},
$$

after $n$ times by parts, and notice that $
\mathrm{Re}\left( \gamma \right) >0,\mathrm{Re}\left( p-\gamma +1 \right) >0
$, we have

$$
N_n=\frac{\Gamma \left( \gamma \right)}{\Gamma \left( \gamma +n \right)}\left( -1 \right) ^n\int_0^1{z^{\gamma +n-1}\left( 1-z \right) ^{p+n-\gamma}\frac{\mathrm{d}^nw_n}{\mathrm{d}z^n}\mathrm{d}z}=\frac{\Gamma \left( \gamma \right)}{\Gamma \left( \gamma +n \right)}\frac{\left( p+n \right) _n}{\left( \gamma \right) _n}n!\int_0^1{z^{\gamma +n-1}\left( 1-z \right) ^{p+n-\gamma}\mathrm{d}z}=\frac{\left( p+n \right) _n}{\left( \gamma \right) _n}\frac{\Gamma \left( \gamma \right) \Gamma \left( p+n-\gamma +1 \right)}{\Gamma \left( p+2n+1 \right)}n!.
$$

where the second equal sign used the definition of Jacobi polynomials, and the third equal sign used the first kind Euler integration which reads

$$
B\left( \mu ,\nu \right) =\int_0^1{z^{\mu -1}\left( 1-z \right) ^{\nu -1}\mathrm{d}z}=\frac{\Gamma \left( \mu \right) \Gamma \left( \nu \right)}{\Gamma \left( \mu +\nu \right)}.
$$

Then we come to the Gegenbauer one. Notice that the hypergeometric representation of Gegenbauer polynomials given by

$$
C_{n}^{\lambda}\left( x \right) =\frac{\left( 2\lambda \right) _n}{n!}\cdot _2F_1\left( -n,2\lambda +n,\frac{1}{2}+\lambda ,\frac{1-x}{2} \right) 
$$

After comparing the definition of Jacobi and hypergeometric representation of Gegenbauer, we let  $p=2\lambda,\gamma=\lambda+1/2,z=\left(1-x\right)/2$ apparently, and the Jacobi orthogonal coefficient have the relation with Gegenbauer's as follow

$$
\int_0^1{w_{n}^{2}z^{\gamma -1}\left( 1-z \right) ^{p-\gamma}\mathrm{d}z}=\int_0^1{\left[ \frac{n!}{\left( 2\lambda \right) _n}C_{n}^{\lambda}\left( x \right) \right] ^2\left( \frac{1-x}{2} \right) ^{\lambda -1/2}\left( \frac{1+x}{2} \right) ^{\lambda -1/2}\mathrm{d}\left( \frac{1-x}{2} \right)}=\left[ \frac{n!}{\left( 2\lambda \right) _n} \right] ^2\frac{1}{2^{2\lambda}}\int_{-1}^1{\left[ C_{n}^{\lambda}\left(x\right) \right] ^2\left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda -1/2}\mathrm{d}x},
$$

where the last term contained the Gegenbauer orthogonal coefficient, we denote it as $
I_n=\int_{-1}^1{\left[ C_{n}^{\lambda}\left( x \right) \right] ^2\left( 1-x^2 \right) ^{\lambda -1/2}\mathrm{d}x}
$, then the relation comes

$$
I_n=\frac{2^{2\lambda}}{n!}\frac{\left[ \Gamma \left( \lambda +\frac{1}{2} \right) \right] ^2\Gamma \left( 2\lambda +n \right)}{\left[ \Gamma \left( 2\lambda \right) \right] ^2\cdot 2\left( \lambda +n \right)}=\frac{2^{2\lambda}}{n!}\frac{\left[ \Gamma \left( \lambda +\frac{1}{2} \right) \Gamma \left( \lambda \right) \right] ^2\Gamma \left( 2\lambda +n \right)}{\left[ \Gamma \left( 2\lambda \right) \right] ^2\left[ \Gamma \left( \lambda \right) \right] ^2\cdot 2\left( \lambda +n \right)}.
$$

Then using the multiplication formula of Gamma function:

$$
\Gamma \left( z \right) \Gamma \left( z+\frac{1}{n} \right) \Gamma \left( z+\frac{2}{n} \right) \cdots \Gamma \left( z+\frac{n-1}{n} \right) =\left( 2\pi \right) ^{\frac{n-1}{2}}n^{\frac{1}{2}-nz}\Gamma \left( nz \right) 
$$

where $n=2$ is enough. Then back to the $I_n$ reduces to

$$
I_n=\frac{2^{2\lambda}}{n!}\frac{\left[ \left( 2\pi \right) ^{1/2}2^{1/2-2\lambda}\Gamma \left( 2\lambda \right) \right] ^2\Gamma \left( 2\lambda +n \right)}{\left[ \Gamma \left( 2\lambda \right) \right] ^2\left[ \Gamma \left( \lambda \right) \right] ^2\cdot 2\left( \lambda +n \right)}=\frac{2^{2\lambda}}{n!}\frac{2\pi \cdot 2^{1-4\lambda}\Gamma \left( 2\lambda +n \right)}{2\left( \lambda +n \right) \left[ \Gamma \left( \lambda \right) \right] ^2}=\frac{\pi \Gamma \left( 2\lambda +n \right)}{2^{2\lambda -1}n!\left( \lambda +n \right) \left[ \Gamma \left( \lambda \right) \right] ^2}.
$$

which is exactly you wanted.

Comment: maybe some typos... wrote in a rush..